# Selecting unique players' scores from two columns with bubble sorting

Tags: mysql, sql, rdbms

I have a very interesting challenge that I'm either looking too hard at (and missing a simple solution), or it is more complex than I can figure out heh

Essentially, I have a game that tracks scores. The table named `scores` has the columns:

`id` (pk, ai), `email`, `name`, `duration`, `moves`

A player (identified by email) can have multiple rows. To determine the winners, we apply bubble sorting on duration then moves. The challenge is this: How do we get a unique list (by email) of winners?

`GROUP BY` doesn't work as expected because this is an aggregate. We need to keep parity between duration and moves.

Here's an example of the schema and problem: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b1530/2 -- notice how the same emails show up as expected.

This example uses GROUP BY, but it selects the wrong data: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b1530/3 -- notice how baz@biz.com's score is incorrect. The correct score should be `30`, `31` (duration & moves, respectively). cow@guy.com should show `31`, `35` (duration & moves, respectively)

And then lastly, selecting distinct on email column won't work here either, example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b1530/4

I've tried a few JOIN's, but I cannot get those to work and also keep row parity either.

---

**UPDATE #1**

- The highest score is the amalgamation of *first* the lowest `duration` and then the lowest `moves` count
- The expected results from my example are:

```
email         name      duration   moves
foo@bar.com   foo bar   20         36
baz@biz.com   baz biz   30         31
cow@guy.com   cow guy   31         35
```

---

**UPDATE #2**

Due to JSFiddle limitations, I've moved everything over to https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vV7XMKkoFaynYEajLtYm9h/2

Please note that some of the queries in your answers do not work. I've used real data here (except changed emails/names) so that answers can test real data.

Here are the expected results from this sample data:

```
email           duration    moves
dp@dp.com       32          22
bw@bw.com       33          21
m@m.com         38          23
s@s.com         40          25
foo@bar.com     41          22
```

Comment: What is *bubble sorting on duration then moves*? You would probably need to share the results that you expect, in order to clarify your requirement.

Comment: Which version of MySQL? More recent ones support the [ROW_NUMBER()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_row-number) window function.

Comment: @GMB good point, I'll add this shortly.

Comment: @Uueerdo We're currently using 5.7

Comment: Do you care about submitted time for the result?

Comment: @Nick no, I do not.

Comment: @HalfCrazed ignore the first half of my answer then...

Comment: Thanks @Nick. Can you check my update #2? I'm running into some strangeness (which reflects the same issue on our database as well)

Comment: @HalfCrazed so why do you only have results from some of the emails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is using two nested `IN` expressions. The inner expression finds all combinations of email and duration that have the lowest duration for that email. The outer expression then finds the email, duration and moves values that are the lowest moves value for that duration (which is the lowest for that email).

```
SELECT *
FROM scores
WHERE (email, duration, moves) IN (
    SELECT email, duration, MIN(moves)
    FROM scores
    WHERE (email, duration) IN (
        SELECT email, MIN(duration)
        FROM scores
        GROUP BY email)
    GROUP BY email, duration)
ORDER BY duration, moves
```

Output:

```
id      email           name        duration    moves   submitted
219     foo@bar.com     foo bar     20          36      2019-12-09T20:36:19Z
224     baz@biz.com     baz biz     30          31      2019-12-09T20:36:19Z
233     cow@guy.com     cow guy     31          35      2019-12-09T20:36:19Z
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b1530/36)

If you don't care about the submitted time, you can remove the outer nested expression:

```
SELECT email, name, duration, MIN(moves) AS moves
FROM scores
WHERE (email, duration) IN (
    SELECT email, MIN(duration)
    FROM scores
    GROUP BY email)
GROUP BY email, name, duration
ORDER BY duration, moves
```

Output:

```
email           name        duration    moves
foo@bar.com     foo bar     20          36
baz@biz.com     baz biz     30          31
cow@guy.com     cow guy     31          35
```

[Demo on SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b1530/43)

[Demo with full data on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vV7XMKkoFaynYEajLtYm9h/4)

Comment: My answer is quite a bit shorter.  It's a simple group-wise problem.

Comment: @avejidah your answer won't give the correct submitted time.

Comment: Sure it will.  I just didn't include it in the column selection because it wasn't requested in the original unedited question.

Comment: @avejidah no it won't, because it's not in the `group by` it will give you an error in MySQL 5.7, and if you use 5.6 (which is not OPs version), it will give you an indeterminate answer

Comment: Ah.  Yes, you're correct.  If `submitted` is needed then my answer would need a nested query.

Comment: Hi @Nick - can you please see my Update #2 in question? I'm unable to get your query to return the correct result set. I've added real data so that you can see the difference. I didn't realize my small sample set was insufficient. Thank you!

Comment: @Nick it looks like your last answer, when I add the `order by duration asc, moves asc` works correctly!

Comment: I was just in the process of adding that https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vV7XMKkoFaynYEajLtYm9h/4

Answer (score 2):

I think you want the group-wise min duration for each player, and then the min moves of each grouping.

```
SELECT  s.email, s.duration, MIN(s.moves)
FROM    scores s
LEFT OUTER JOIN scores s_min ON s.email = s_min.email
  AND s.duration > s_min.duration
WHERE  s_min.id IS NULL
GROUP BY s.email, s.duration
ORDER BY s.duration, MIN(s.moves)
```

Here's a fiddle that shows the winners: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b1530/56

```
foo@bar.com 20  36
baz@biz.com 30  31
cow@guy.com 31  35
```

Comment: Hi @avejidah - can you please see my Update #2 in question? I'm unable to get your query to return the correct result set. I've added real data so that you can see the difference. Thank you!

Comment: Is the difference just the order?  I updated the answer.

Comment: You need to change your `ORDER BY` to `ORDER BY s.duration, MIN(s.moves)`

Comment: As far as I can tell this does now produce exactly the same results, so you should get an upvote too...